# Can we update user's nickname with admin token?

Tags: quickblox

I tried to update a user's nickname using admin token and I received error response
'You are not owner of this object'.

Is it possible for admin to update a user's nickname?
Document found at
https://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Update_API_User_by_identifier

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to update user's nickname using Admin Token.
In this case, you are able to update it in Admin Panel.

Comment: Thank you for the response, is it possible to has more control on user such as update user's nickname or retrieve user's message with Admin Token in the future?